# Joining different values in columns, within the same table, into one row

Tags: sql

I currently have a table in the following format and with the following example data:

```
transaction  name  receipt
     1       jim   aisjdy
     2       john  uuyjskl
     2       john  ioxiqo
     3       will  eurique
     1       jim   xoqiel
     3       will  sijcjg
```

Each transaction is associated with the customer's name and they receive two separate receipts.

How would one go about creating a query that would display 'transaction', 'name' and the two different receipts in one row?

Example:

```
transaction  name  receipt  receipt
     1       jim    aisjdy   xoqiel
```

I know this is bad practice and, in an idea world, I'd have created two columns containing the two different receipts and/or normalized the table into two tables containing transaction and name in one, and receipt 1 and 2 in another.  Unfortunately, I did not produce this table and I do not have the time to restructure everything.

I would kindly appreciate any help - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are only two values, you can use group by:

```
select transaction, name, min(receipt), max(receipt)
from t
group by transaction, name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but something like this would work:

```
SELECT
    tr1.transaction,
    tr1.name,
    tr1.receipt AS receipt1,
    tr2.receipt AS receipt2
FROM transaction tr1
    JOIN transaction tr2 ON tr1.transaction = tr2.transaction
        AND tr1.receipt < tr2.receipt
```

This works only if there are exactly two records for each transaction, but it would also work if you knew there were always any specific number (you would just join and make sure that tr2.receipt < tr3.receipt, etc).  However, as long as there are only two, Gordon's answer is easier to understand and almost certainly faster.